# What is the output? C Programming

Tags: c, coding-style, logic

Was just posed an elementary programming question that I've somehow overlooked.

```
int a = 2, b = 3, c = 5;

if (!a == b)
    c = a--;
else
    c = ++b;

printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
```

I think the output should be 2 4 4.
Anyone can help verify whether I'm correct or wrong and why?

Comment: What happens when you compile and run the code?

Comment: The answer is [here](http://ideone.com/YaZTUm).

Comment: That doesn't answer *why* though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: `!a` giver you `0` and `0 == b` is `0`,

So, `c = ++b` gives `b = 4` and `c = 4`.  The `a` is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Since `!` has higher precedence than `==` the condition of the `if` will be false `((!a) == b) -> (0 == 3)`. So the else will be executed, and b and c will both be set to 4. You were correct.